# Ubuntu 14.04: Upgrade to php7 and uninstall php5?

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu-14.04, php-7, php-5.5

I'm upgrading the php version to 7.0 in my docker image which is based on Ubuntu 14.04. I read some articles giving the commands to uninstall php5 while installing php7.0. Is this really necessary? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using the versions on hub.docker.com?

Comment: You can have both installed, just make sure that your files point to the right version, or that the correct version is in your PATH.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: @jay I'm a developer not a devops. That's why I tend to use stackoverflow. However, if the question does not fit stackoverflow requirements I can delete it.

Comment: @JonStirling when I don't need to make a specific image I use the images available on dockerhub. However, sometimes, I need to install different softwares, activate modules and so on. In these situations, it's necessary to write your own image.

Comment: @unadivadantan That's fine, but then you just start from the PHP7 base instead of the PHP5 one.

Comment: @JonStirling, sorry, I hadn't understand your comment. In this specific case, my app uses the ubuntu 14.04 image which comes with PHP5.5. I cannot upgrade the ubuntu version for other reasons so I have to upgrade the php. Otherwise, I would prefer to start from the 16.04 ;)

Answer (score 6):

add the new repository for PHP 7:

```
 apt-get install software-properties-common
 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

remove PHP 5 from your system and install PHP 7

```
 apt-get update && apt-get purge php5-fpm && apt-get --purge autoremove && apt-get install php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-opcache php7.0-xml
```

see this article for more details

https://bjornjohansen.no/upgrade-to-php7